# How can I tie the Display Face Orientation to a Toggleable hotkey?

Tags: interface, workflow, shortcut

I already have the... thing:

> bpy.context.space_data.overlay.show_face_orientation

This accepts a boolean value. I found this out by looking at the Info menu.

I think it's called a context attribute?

I just don't know how to set its value to True or False with a toggleable hotkey.

Comment: @RobinBetts why answer as a comment instead of as an answer? 
It's the second time I see this phenomenon. And yes, that answers it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2.8x, it's simpler than that. Just open the overlays panel, right-click the Face Orientation check-box, and select 'Assign Shortcut' from the menu.